# Python: 401k Finance Loop

Tags: python, finance

I'm working on a financial model for people's 401k that uses a random return rate for every year in the equation. I am wondering how I get the return rate to change from one to the next while doing the loop. In other words I want a random return rate used everytime the wax ball is being calculated for each year.

For example,
Year 1 2000 * 1.10 = 2,200
Year 2 2,100 * 1.2 = 2,520*

*This does not include the wax_ball & contribution variables from my code. My problem seems to be with the choice function...I have it imported to pick from 3 different return rates.

Below is my code.

Thanks for your help.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
print "How much do you want to contribute to your 401k?"
contribution = int(raw_input())
# money contributed to 401k
print "What is your 401k worth now?"
wax_ball = int(raw_input())
# sum of all contribution plus interest of every year
print "When do you want to withdraw on it?"
time= int(raw_input())
# time in years
interest_rate = [.25,.1,.01]
#average return rate randomized

from random import choice

choice(interest_rate)

for x in range (0, time):
    wax_ball= contribution+(wax_ball*(1+interest_rate))
print round(wax_ball,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different rate for each iteration of the loop, you can use:

```
for x in range (time):
    wax_ball= contribution+(wax_ball*(1+choice(interest_rate)))
```